# Can Siri be disabled within an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, siri

I'm working an on iOS game and recently tested on an iPhone 4S. Siri activates sometimes when my thumb covers the proximity sensor. This is a feature of the 4S. Instead of holding the home button, users can put the phone to their ear to activate Siri. But in my game the activation is not intended and it interrupts gameplay.

Can Siri be disabled within an app? Is this an iPhone 4S bug?

Comment: perhaps you could turn it into something useful: "finish this game for me".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple deprecated support for this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/proximitySensingEnabled

I'd file a bug report.

> Discussion
>   YES if proximity sensing is enabled; otherwise NO. **Enabling proximity sensing tells iOS that it may need to blank the screen if the user's face is near it. Proximity sensing is disabled by default.**

This the replacement which only allows you to get notification, not disable it.

> Discussion 
>   **Enable proximity monitoring only when your application
>   needs to be notified of changes to the proximity state**. Otherwise,
>   disable proximity monitoring. The default value is NO.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW25

Comment: They replaced that property with equivalent functionality (`-proximityMonitoringEnabled`) in another class (`UIDevice`.)

Comment: No, you could actually disable it before. You can no longer do that. I suggest you read the docs more closely.

Comment: I have read the docs. `-proximityMonitoringEnabled` is read/write.

Comment: It only disables notifications, NOT proximity monitoring, which is what the deprecated function did.

Answer (score 6):

Setting :

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
```

Disables Siri from activating when you activate the proximity sensor.  As a result although, it blacks out the screen when the proximity sensor is activated instead.

Comment: Is this the best way for disable Siri ? proximity monitor is power hog.