# iPhone Siri Raise to talk during a VoIP call

Tags: iphone, siri

I am coding a SIP App for iPhone using PJSIP library..

I noticed that when Siri "Raise to Talk " option is enabled through the system settings, Siri starts when i raise the phone to answer a phone call.

Is there anyways i can disable this feature thru my App temporally in xcode so it does not start during a phone call..

I checked Skype and it was doing it correctly, Siri will not start during a phone call.

I did some research but i could not find any Siri API.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Siri be disabled within an app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881167/can-siri-be-disabled-within-an-app)

Comment: see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW25