# Can Siri be disabled when using the microphone?

Tags: ios4, audio-recording, siri

My app records things with the microphone, and on the 4S Siri sometimes activates during recording. Is there a way for my app to tell Siri to relax while I'm using the microphone for something else?

I found this related question: [Can Siri be disabled within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881167/can-siri-be-disabled-within-an-app), but it's all about the proximity sensor.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to prevent siri is enabling the proximity. You can refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW25