# Disabling Siri in an app

Tags: objective-c, siri

Is there any way to completely disable Siri within the app?  I am not only talking about the proximity sensor, but the long-press on the home key as well.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Siri be disabled within an app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881167/can-siri-be-disabled-within-an-app)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Not quite, he's talking about the long-press in addition to the proximity sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's impossible to override the functionality of the home button. In general, Apple does not allow you to modify the behavior of something that is outside of the scope of your app.